# Only one subscriber receives responses from server

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

Using RxJs and WebSockets i created a couple services that are supposed to receive data from a server and send it out to subscribers of the services in my program. When I only had 1 service, there were no problems, but after creating the second one, the first one does not receive responses anymore. How do I make sure it does?

Here is my WebSocket service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
        this.subject = this.create(url);
    }
    return this.subject;
}

private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

    let observable = Rx.Observable.create(
        (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
            ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

            return ws.close.bind(ws);
        })

    let observer = {
        next: (data: Object) => {
            if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        }
    }

    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
}
}
```

And this my countdown service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {WebSocketService } from './websocket.service';

const AUCTION_URL = 'ws://localhost:9999';

export interface Countdown {
days: number,
hours: number,
minutes: number,
seconds: number
}

@Injectable()
export class CountdownService {
public countdowns: Subject<Countdown>;

constructor(wsService: WebSocketService) {
    this.countdowns = <Subject<Countdown>>wsService
        .connect(AUCTION_URL)
        .map((response: MessageEvent): Countdown => {
            let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
            return {
                days: data.days,
                hours: data.hours,
                minutes: data.minutes,
                seconds: data.seconds
            }
        });
}
}
```

The other service is implemented the same way as the countdown service but with other variables.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the service being used across multiple components? I would check that the service is only being instantiated once.

You can also ensure that by adding the share operator to the observable create:

```
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(
        (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
            ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

            return ws.close.bind(ws);
        }).share()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do that, I get this error:
(SystemJS) wsService is not defined(…)

Comment: need to use this.wsService

Comment: Changed that, now I get this error:
(SystemJS) Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined(…)

Comment: I think the share part needs to be on `this.subject = this.create(url).share();`

Comment: @echonax That gives me an error: 
app/websocket.service.ts(10,13): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<MessageEvent>' is not assignable to type 'Subject<MessageEvent>'.
  Property 'observers' is missing in type 'Observable<MessageEvent>'.